# cannot import name 'IsOwnerorReadOnly' (function) from 'snippets.permissions' (django python file)

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-views, django-permissions

so in django rest framework app, i created a file called permissions.py which looks like this-

```
# snippets/permissions.py

from rest_framework import permissions


class IsOwnerOrReadOnly(permissions.BasePermission):
    """
    Custom permission to only allow owners of an object to edit it.
    """

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        # Read permissions are allowed to any request,
        # so we'll always allow GET, HEAD or OPTIONS requests.
        if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            return True

        # Write permissions are only allowed to the owner of the snippet.
        return obj.owner == request.user
```

and views.py looks like this

```
# snippets/views.py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework import generics, permissions

from .models import Snippet
from .serializers import SnippetSerializer, UserSerializer
from .permissions import IsOwnerorReadOnly

# Create your views here.

class SnippetList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Snippet.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SnippetSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)

class SnippetDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Snippet.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SnippetSerializer
    permission_classes = (
        permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,
        IsOwnerOrReadOnly,
    )  # new  

class UserList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

class UserDetail(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

now when i run the server i get an error as the following:

[image]

can you tell me why this is happening and how may i fix it?

Comment: It is `IsOwnerOrReadOnly`, with a three capital `O`s.

Comment: Dang thanks! You have no idea how much time I spent on this extremely silly mistake.

Comment: well unfortunately my experience is that the most silly mistakes take extreme amounts of time, so it is not that strange :P

Comment: Use Visual Studio Code, for better coding experience, it helps in avoiding typo